# Django and SphinxQL - how to disable transactions?

Tags: django, transactions, sphinx

I have to use a SphinxQL in Django, but SphinxQL seems doesn't support transaction. How to disable transactions for SphinxQL connection? Is it possible? I replaced Django MySQL backend with `MySQLdb` and it works, but I prefer using native Django components.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage that via

```
set autocommit=0
insert
...
commit
set autocommit=1
```